Upgrade 22.04 Jammy to 24.04 Noble: Oh no! Something has gone wrong
I used do-release-upgrade many times in over a decade of using Ubuntu. This is the first time this happened. In the middle of the upgrade a (white screen of death?) message showed up:

Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.

What happened? Any way to resolve this or prevent this from happening?
I can't access the system or the upgrade messages after the error came out. (Good thing BTRFS + Timeshift + timeshift-autosnap-apt + grub-btrfs saved me. I guess this stack should be considered part of a default Ubuntu install.)
I know, LTS are supposed to be upgraded on the first point release. And this is release day one. I'm excited, that's why.
Looks like a beta-version bug was reported here for the same issue. I'm on an official release though, not beta. (Today is release day. ) So this should have supposedly been ironed out before the release?
More digs on the error: Mutter, systemd-resolved?

I wish I could put the logs. Only that there's nothing you can do anymore with the system when it crashes. Others reported not being able to boot after this error. Anyways, it seems to be a known and triaged bug already. It seems that all we need now is to wait until they could push the fix to the repos.

The official upgrade paths have not opened yet. When it does, the update manager would tell you that the upgrade is available. Users are being advised not to upgrade till the official upgrade path opens up https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/dont-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-yet

Any way to resolve this? -- Fresh install 24.04. That should not cause any problems. The upgrades are not working right now.

Yep. Patience is the key.

Does this answer your question? Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 (Answer also covers upgrade from 22.04)

I got the same error right after switching from 22.04 to 24.04 (I could only log in via Wayland, but this time, even though I clicked on system settings and files, it wasn't opening and the mouse was laggy).
This time, when I wanted to open system settings via the terminal, I received an error like libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen. When I did a little research, I saw problems with the graphics driver.
Nvidia-535 was already installed in the system. After installing nvidia-550 the problem was solved.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550

I logged in with Xorg and Wayland and haven't seen any problems.

Same error here with libEGL. After installing nvidia-driver-550 the error is gone, but the "Oh no!" error remains.

I'm sorry it happened like this, but I still have no problem.
